# Workflow task - How to set priority when assigning a task

Tags: 2013, workflow, tasks

When assigning a workflow task in SharePoint 2013, how can I set the priority? By default it is set to "(2) Normal".

Comment: How is your workflow defined. Using SharePoint Designer or Visual Studio? What activity are you using?

Comment: The workflow is defined using SharePoint Designer 2013. Using "Assign a task" I am able to define the description and other task related items, but I do not see a way to define the priority when assigning a task.

Answer (score 0):

I am having this issue as well, as best I can see this is the only way around it, (note I am using a 2013 List Workflow)

- Add a Yes/No column to the List the workflow is subscribed to called "Continue Workflow". Set this field to No before assigning the task.
- Add a Lookup column called "Workflow Item" to your Tasks list referencing the list the workflow will be run on.
- In Task Options in the action, untick 'wait for task completion' and use an 'Update Item' action to modify any fields you want to change, as well as giving the task a reference back to the current item.
- Create a workflow for your Tasks list that waits until the task is set to complete, and then updates the Continue Workflow column in the list item the original workflow is running on using the lookup column we created.
- Kick this workflow off on the Task you created in the original workflow using the REST API - good luck here.
- After the 'Assign a Task' and 'Update Item' actions in the original workflow, add a "Wait for field in current item" action that waits for "Continue Workflow" to be set to Yes by the Tasks workflow.

This seems like a gross amount of effort just to modify all the fields in the Task you want to assign, so I'd like to know if there is an easier way available.